# Impact on long call options

Tags: call-options

Anyone know the impact on long call options when a company reorganizes and issues new equity thereby diluting the shares? Are they unchanged or do my options increase proportionately with the dilution of the share base?

Comment: `long call options` You long or the expiry of the call options is far into the future ? Secondly how is it related to Personal Finance ? Elaborate a bit or you will start getting close votes.

Answer (score 2):

If there is simply share dilution and the share price drops, your options decrease in value in accordance with the greeks, unrelated to the dilution

If there is a split, then your options split too.

Answer (score 0):

If a company issues new shares, it has no affect on the contractual terms of your option.  The number of shares covered by the contract (usually 100), the strike price, and the expiration date  all remain the same.

The only affect on your option will be the market's perception of the corporate event.  If it is  favorable and share price increases enough, your  long call benefits.  If not favorable, it will suffer